# How to get the xml attribute value of root?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

Q:

How to get the attribute value of the root element(first element in my xml file) through LINQ.

## .cs :

```
 XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(targetFileName);
```

## .xml :

```
<timetable ascttversion="2010"  options="idprefix:realID">
```

I want to read the `options` value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(targetFileName);
var attrib = xdoc.Root.Attribute("options").Value;

// attrib = "idprefix:realID"
```

Comment: hmmmm, i want to read the `options` value from the file it self i mean using `xmlDoc`.

Comment: because according to your code the `options` will be the same value all the time

Comment: Right, you should just do XDocument.Load() instead of XDocument.Parse() as you already have -- I just did XDocument.Parse() as an example.  I can update the sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Following should do

```
xmlDoc.Root.Attribute("option").Value
```